# Подключение шрифтов в scss

Tags: html, scss

Не подключаются шрифты.

Моя структура проекта:

```
-project
  -dist
    -js
      file.js
    -css
      file.css
    -fonts
      file.ttf
  -src
    -js
      file.js
      ...
    -scss
      stule.scss
      -utils
        fonts.scss
        ...
    -fonts
      file.ttf
      ...
  index.html
```

В `fonts.scss` подключаю так

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto-Medium;
  src: local("Roboto-Medium"),
  url(../fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf) format("ttf");
}
```

В `style.scss` использую так:

```
@import "utils/fonts";
...

.landing__description-title {
  font-family: "Roboto-Medium";
  width: $landingWidhtTitle;
  ...
}
```

Но когда собираю проект в `webpack` на странице `index.html` шрифт не работает, остальные стили работают.

Если меняю путь с `url(../fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf) format("ttf");` на `url(../../fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf) format("ttf");` выдает ошибку `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf' in 'C:\Users\qwe\webpack-starter\src\scss'`/ 
В чем моя проблема заключается?

Comment: Если заменить `url(../fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf) format("ttf");` на `url(../fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf) format("truetype");` ?

Comment: Ты лучше свой `webpack` покажи. И еще шрифтам в `scss` делать нечего. Подключи их отдельным `css - файлом`

Comment: Заработало. Что это за зверь `format("truetype");`?

Comment: С `webpack` все в прорядке, он ложет куда надо

Comment: Не знаю, но у меня он есть... Стоял во всех скаченных файлах

Comment: Но я его убрал и все же работает. Все же я остаюсь при своем мнение. Фонты надо подключать отдельным файлом...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верить [источнику](https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/d0460e5c2d5d7f9bc5e6), то нужно правильно указать тип шрифта ttf. Т.е. заменить

```
format("ttf")
```

на:

```
format("truetype")
```